# How is "Microsoft Build Tools 2015" different from "Visual C++ Build Tools 2015"?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, build

In order to compile a few Python modules, following https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers, I just tried to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 standalone: Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 (x86, x64, ARM)".

I found the installer here [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159), but:

- strangely the Full installer "BuildTools_Full.exe" (not Net install) is only 24.4 MB, and ~ 124 MB once installed (so obviously all the SDK is not installed)
- This option: "Windows SDK":

  > Install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015. Check Windows 8.1 SDK and Windows 10 SDK options.

  was not offered during the install process.

  [image]
- the compiler `cl.exe` is not even present on my whole system after the full successful install

**Question: what is actually [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) if it does not install any compiler and/or SDK?**

And where can one get the real "Visual C++ Build Tools 2015"?

Note:

- I'd like to use this one and not newer because of compatibility with previous builds I made
- I don't want to install Visual Studio but only the standalone build tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: I don't know exactly what is [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) but it is **definitely different from** [Microsoft *Visual C++* Build Tools 2015](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/7/5F7ACAEB-8363-451F-9425-68A90F98B238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe) that we can find here:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

[image]

The answer gives [Where can I download Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools?](https://superuser.com/questions/1369402/where-can-i-download-visual-c-2015-build-tools/1369439#1369439) more information about this.