# Compile zbar for Python 3.x

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, zbar, build-tools

A few years ago I spent some time finding a way to make `zbar` work with Python 2.7 + Windows x64, and I posted this working solution: [How to decode a QR-code image in (preferably pure) Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233351/how-to-decode-a-qr-code-image-in-preferably-pure-python/50435929#50435929)

Now I notice `pip install zbar` still does not work out-of-the-box with Python 3.7, so I'm trying to compile it from source. Here is what I did:

- Install "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968336/how-is-microsoft-build-tools-2015-different-from-visual-c-build-tools-2015/59969042#59969042))
- Get the `zbar` source from: https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/ZBarWin64
- `msbuild zbar64.sln /p:PlatformToolset=v140`, which worked and produced a file `libzbar64-0.dll` succesfully
- copy it to `/x64/Release/libzbar64-0.dll`
- go to `Python/` and run `build.bat` but here it failed:

  > zbarmodule.c(132): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  >
  >   zbarmodule.c(136): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  >   zbarmodule.c(197): error C2065: 'PyInt_Type': undeclared identifier

I don't think the problem comes from `zbar` which compiles fine for everyone. **Could it be that this version of zbar is not ok for Python 3.x?**

**Do you have a working solution to use the `zbar` library on Python 3.x + Windows x64?**

---

PS: is it still maintained? The latest events seem to be in 2012 on the [Mercurial repo](http://zbar.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/zbar/zbar), and it's not possible to post an issue on [this Github repo](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar) nor [this one](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/ZBarWin64/).

Comment: `pip install pyzbar` can work for Python 3.x

Comment: @yushulx yes it might be the time to forget about https://pypi.org/project/zbar/, and use https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/ instead. Do you want to post this as an answer? It might be the best option as of today.

Comment: sure, why not :)

Answer (score 1):

To make zbar work for Python 3.x, you can install `pyzbar`

```
pip install pyzbar
```